# How to add an integer to a string variable using regex (field $) in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a jquery code that works correctly but i want to use a string variable in an addition operation.

there is my jquery code:

```
var valueName1 = $("#Name1").val();
var rege2 = /^([1]{1,1})(T)+\_([A-Za-z]{2,4})+\_([A-Za-z0-9_]{3,40})+\_([0-9]{2,8})+\_([A-Za-z]{1,1})+([0-9]{1,1})$/;

if (rege2.test(valueName1)){
$("#Name2").val(valueName1.replace(rege, '4'+'$2_$3_$4_'+$("#type2").val()+'_$6'+ '$7' ));
$("#Name3").val(valueName1.replace(rege, '4'+'$2_$3_$4_'+$("#type3").val()+'_$6'+ '$7'));
}
```

I captured fileds from regex and I use them in a replace fonction but i want to add integer number to the $7 field ex:

```
 $("#Name2").val(valueName1.replace(rege, '4'+'$2_$3_$4_'+$("#type2").val()+'_$6'+ ('$7'+1) ));
```

I tried:

```
$("#Name2").val(valueName1.replace(rege, '4'+'$2_$3_$4_'+$("#type2").val()+'_$6'+ parseInt('$7', 10) + 1 ));
```

But doesn't wokr.

Please how can I add an integer to $7 variable.

Comment: You need a callback function. Could you provide a sample string?

Comment: Can you help me please?

Comment: `String.prototype.replace()`: [Specifying a function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Comment: If you want numeric addition, it might be a good idea to convert the strings to numbers with `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` first, otherwise "2"+"3" = "23"

Comment: I tried parseInt('$7', 10) + 1 and also parseInt('$7') + 1 but doesn't work

Comment: [Here is what I meant](http://jsfiddle.net/0skawmqa/). I see you already accepted another solution, glad you solved your issue.

Comment: Thank you stribizhev for your help I will try the two solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set temporarily an hidden field with $7 and then extract it and convert to integer with parseInt, summing 1 to the result. Something like this:

```
$("#temporary_hidden_field").val(valueName1.replace(rege, '$7'));
$("#Name2").val(parseInt($("#temporary_hidden_field").val(),10)+1);
```

Note that the same can be accomplished by setting a temporary JS variable instead of an hidden field:

```
var temp=valueName1.replace(rege, '$7')
$("#Name2").val(parseInt(temp,10)+1);
```

Be sure to handle possible conversion errors, also (`parseInt()` returning `NaN`).